# Detect neterror of iframe (external site)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

There was a problem that the external site that I had to bring as an iframe did not appear with a probability of about 5%. (If you click again, it will appear normally)

[image]

I want to retry if there is an error in the external site imported into the iframe.
How can I detect that an error has occurred on an external site?

- class list: neterror, sub-frame-error-details, sub-frame-error, main-frame-error)
  [image]

I tried to find the html tag or class name of the external site imported into the iframe but failed.
[image]

And the onload function didn't work as expected either.
This is because even if I call 'an external site with an error', 'my site' is judged as 'imported'.

Summary: How do I know on my own site that an error occurred on someone else's site that was imported into an iframe?
My site judged that 'it was imported normally', so functions such as onerror did not work.

I asked the developer of an external site that imports into an iframe for help.
However, he did not know the exact cause.

---

Differences from this question:
[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

- Normally, it is called normally.
- The external site itself occasionally encounters network errors. (not my promblem)
- As an analogy, my site shows the YouTube site as an iframe, which is exactly the same as the situation where YouTube's server is unstable and cannot show the video. The YouTube site itself is called normally.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

Comment: The site I import as an iframe is not my own. (someone else's site)
Should I send a separate request to the developer of the external site?

Comment: No, read the answer. You cannot access information inside of another iframe via your domain.

Comment: Differences from this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

- Normally, it is called normally.

- The external site itself occasionally encounters network errors. (not my promblem)

- As an analogy, Google shows the YouTube site as an iframe, which is exactly the same as the situation where YouTube's server is unstable and cannot show the video. The YouTube site itself is called normally.

Comment: Well, your question is very unclearly written. You can fetch it through the fetch-api, check if the response is 200, then decide to add it to the DOM or not.

Comment: I added a picture to explain my situation in detail. 

(Similar to the situation below, to paraphrase it.)
1. I brought the YouTube site itself normally
2. However, the video cannot be displayed on the YouTube site due to a network error. (The homepage works normally)

Comment: Sorry for using Google Translate because I can't speak English :(
I sent the 'extract hits' api to an external site. But the api is 200.

Comment: I asked an external site developer to 'please allow my site to access your site's html'.
I waiting for a reply if they will allow my site url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look into your possibilities. I will tell you in advance that there are no easy solutions. But you have some means to try and solve this.

First of all, look into [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) and event listeners upon the `message` event. If the site you use happens to support your scenario and communicate whether the request has been successful or not, then it is quite possible that you will only need to `addEventListener` upon `message` events and see whatever message the source is sending you.

Secondly, as you pointed out, you may send a message to the owner of the site, describe that your handling of that site is legitimate, convince them that it's their best interest to help you show their side inside your `iframe` and kindly ask them whether they already have some technical support for your case or whether they plan to implement such support.

Finally, if all else fails, your server-side can send the requests to that site and display the content you receive as your page, belonging to the same domain. But this is undesirable and you should only consider using your page as a proxy if you do not violate the legal rights of the owner of the other site.

Comment: Thank you!
I asked an external site developer to 'please allow my site to access your site's html'.
I waiting for a reply if they will allow my site url.